# How to manually rebuild the search index (Index, Main, Ref folders) in EPiServer 7

Tags: episerver, episerver-7

I have seen some custom made gadget for the dashboard and a plugin in admin-mode in EPiServer 6 R2 that will let you rebuild the search index.

What options are there in EPiServer 7?

Are there any official plugin-in/gadgets or some other built-in feature that I have yet to discover?

Is it possible to manually rebuild the entire index without any gadgets/plugins? how?

What is the most common method?

Answer (score 7):

If you're using the built in indexer you should be able to go to http:///EPISERVERUI/cms/admin/indexcontent.aspx (replace EPISERVER-UI with your path) and trigger a reindex.

I'm not that familiar with using the built in indexer, but I think it's using the EPiServer Indexing Service, so make sure that is installed (you can do it using the EPiServer Deployment Center)

Answer (score 3):

Well you can always remove the old index files and restart your iis-service

To reindex by code do this

```
var reIndex = new EPiServer.Search.ReIndexManager();
reIndex.ReIndex();
```